# Booting from USB drive when arrow keys don't work

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, keyboard

I am trying to install Ubuntu using a USB stick. But since my arrow keys on the computer do not work and I do not have access to an external keyboard right now, I would like to know if there is a way to boot from USB so that I can install Ubuntu in the system. Currently I have Windows 10 installed on my machine.

Comment: Doesn't the Ubuntu ISO automatically boot if you don't press any keys?

Comment: No, if I access the bootloader by pressing F12 (Dell), the boot menu shows Hard disk at the top, which will run Windows 10

Comment: Ah... go in the BIOS and change the first/default boot device then (if it doesn't require the arrow keys)

Comment: It does, that's the problem...

Comment: That's a bummer, another keyboard would really solve things... or unplugging the hard drive should completely remove it from the boot list too, only it won't be available to install to when it's in your hand... But some computers + linuxes support hot-swapping hard drives, you might be able to plug it in after Ubuntu's running, then install to it, but it might be a risk to corrupting the drive if it's not fully supported, so I'd definitely have a good backup first